# Detect a sequence inside a bit stream

Tags: digital-logic, design, shift-register, digital-comparator

I was recently in a discussion with my professor in which he told me that 'absolutely in no way would this design work'.  I am hoping I could bounce it off you guys.

The question asked to design (in any way) an IC that, given a sequence of bits which would come as input on a clock cycle, would detect a given sequence (arbitrary, but 4 bit in length) inside that stream of input.

I implemented it with a 4 bit serial in, parallel out shift register whose parallel out fed into a comparator which compared against the desired sequence.

Am I crazy here or missing something? Would love some feedback and or advice!

Comment: "*I implemented it with a 4 bit serial in, parallel out shift register ...*" Well, did it work?

Comment: Very commonly done in serial comms when looking for fixed header information. Your prof needs to open his mind, putting it mildly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the misunderstanding comes from the "4-bit serial-in parallel-out shift register" term. This can be interpreted in two ways:

Deserializer: every 4 clocks it outputs 4 parallel bits.

Shift register: it outputs 4 bits every clock, of which 3 are the shifted output bits from the previous clock cycle, and one is the new bit.

The [HC164](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT164.pdf) which is labeled "serial in parallel out" register behaves like the latter and that was probably what you were thinking about. This is the circuit you need.

If your teacher interpreted it as the former, as a deserializer, then that wouldn't work since it would only detect the pattern if it was aligned on a 4-bit boundary.

Note you don't need a comparator, which usually computes "greater" "lower" and "equal" since you just need an "equal" output signal. As shown by Marcus Muller, XOR gates are enough.

Note the output signal should be registered with a flop. As the register shifts, the output signal will probably glitch so it has to be sampled by a flop after it settles.

Answer (score 0):

That's just a binary correlation you're looking for, so yeah, can be done with a shift register; typically, not of the serial in-parallel out type.

Instead, *convolve* your input stream with the (reversed) sequence you're looking for.

That means, you use the shift register as "delay line", compare the shift register contents with the desired sequence [c0, c1, c2, c3], and make sure *all* the bits in the shift register are identical by combining the result.

```
input-+->[z⁻¹]-+->[z⁻¹]-+->[z⁻¹]-\
      |        |        |        |
      v        v        v        v
     XOR<-c3  XOR<-c2  XOR<-c1  XOR<-c0
      |        |        |        |
      |        v        v        v
      \------->OR------>OR------>OR-->NOT-->detected
```

Pretty standard method to detect a preamble in a binary stream.

So, you are right, it's not hard to detect a short sequence, and your prof is "right", it's not done with deserializers. (which "kind of" are a special case of serial in, parallel out) (Don't let that be a downer – professors typically are professors because they have a bit of experience. The trick is to soak up as much of that experience as possible, instead of being in conflict.)

Comment: I am not familiar with this technique. It seems to me that you've still got the shift register, you've still got the parallel out but you're doing the comparison with XOR rather than a comparator. I'm also curious about false detection as the data is shifted. What's the advantage? Is it that it is well suited to variable length when implemented in software?

Comment: @Transistor I think I got confused, and as peufeu pointed out, confused SIPO shift register with deserializer. Your worries about glitches are understandable, but you could, for example, sample the output on the opposite edge of where the delay elements / flipflops latch (but then you'd need an additional one so that you're not directly depending on the input, which might change at that point).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.